# WPF Image UriSource, Data Binding and Caching

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have this currently working for a databound WPF image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ThumbFile}" />
```

Simple Enough.

Now, adding caching to this Image (I want to be able to manipulate/remove the local file after it has been loaded). I found that you can add a CacheOption="OnLoad" to the  tag within the .

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=ThumbFile, Converter={StaticResource myConverter2}}"  />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Then I had to have a converter to translate the local file to the BitmapImage.

```
<local:LocalUriToImageConverter x:Key="myConverter2"/>
```

and

```
public class LocalUriToImageConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (value is string)
        {
            value = new Uri((string)value);
        }

        if (value is Uri)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bi = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            //bi.DecodePixelWidth = 80;
            bi.DecodePixelHeight = 60;                
            bi.UriSource = (Uri)value;
            bi.EndInit();
            return bi;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

For some reason this doesn't even begin to work. There are no errors but the control does not seem to be bound. Breakpoints in both the get of the ThumbFile property and the Converter do not get reached, even though the control has many instances created. Switching back to the other Image Source tag works fine.

Comment: Nothing in your output window? Failed bindings, etc...?

Comment: Nothing at all. There were a lot of different errors I went through trying to get to the point that it worked, but then it finally stopped erroring while still not actually working.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code what is going on, but I would use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com) to drill down into it and see what is going on. You should be able to see any binding errors and see what the `DataContext` is on the `Image` and make sure the `ThumbFile` property on your DataContext has what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and never found a way to make the binding work with any converter when used on the UriSource property of BitmapImage. I supposed it's not mean to be used this way.

However, I believe the following code is equivalent and should work in your case (worked in mine):

```
<Image Source="{Binding ThumbFile, Converter={StaticResource myConverter2}}" />
```